# Unable to create matrix representing extrinsic Euler rotation

Tags: c++, matrix, geometry, linear-algebra, eigen

I'm trying to create a 4x4 affine transformation matrix from an Euler triplet and a rotation order.  I want the resulting matrix to represent the rotation extrinsically (i.e. fixed frame).  My application uses a left-handed coordinate frame and column vectors.

Following the maths provided by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Extrinsic_rotations) and [VectorAlgebra](http://vectoralgebra.info/euleranglesvector.html), the equation should be:

[image]

However if I rotate an arbitrary amount on the zAxis, the following yAxis or zAxis rotations are performed on the object's *local* equivalent axes.  This is the opposite of what I want!

The code I'm using is below:

```
Matrix4f Sy_3dMath::createRotationMatrix( Axis axis, float radians )
{
    float c = cos( radians );
    float s = sin( radians );

    if ( axis == X ) {
        return ( Matrix4f() << 1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
                               0.0f, c,    -s,    0.0f,
                               0.0f, s,     c,    0.0f,
                               0.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f ).finished();
    } else if ( axis == Y ) {
        return ( Matrix4f() <<  c,    0.0f, s,    0.0f,
                                0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                               -s,    0.0f, c,    0.0f,
                                0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f ).finished();
    } else {
        return ( Matrix4f() << c,   -s,    0.0f, 0.0f,
                               s,    c,    0.0f, 0.0f,
                               0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
                               0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f ).finished();
    }
}

Matrix4f Sy_3dMath::matrixFromEulerAngles( const Vector3f& euler,
                                           Sy_3dMath::RotationOrder order )
{
    EulerData ed = getEulerData( order );
    return createRotationMatrix( static_cast< Axis >( ed.k ), euler( ed.k ) ) *
           createRotationMatrix( static_cast< Axis >( ed.j ), euler( ed.j ) ) *
           createRotationMatrix( static_cast< Axis >( ed.i ), euler( ed.i ) );
}
```

`EulerData` is a simple struct that contains 3 ints that represents the `Axis` index (i.e. 2 == zAxis == k, 0 == xAxis == i).

Can anyone see a flaw in my code or understanding? Linear algebra doesn't exactly come naturally for me...

Comment: Assuming that the code that constructs each axis rotation is correct (you can easily verify), then perhaps (Guessing based on past experience) it's the order of matrix multiplication.  Try reversing the k,j,i to i,j,k.

Comment: @Photon That reversed the order which the rotations are applied, but didn't affect it's 'extrinsic'-ness.

Comment: Actually it does affect. To convert extrinsic and intrinsic Euler angles, the method is just to reverse the application order. Check the wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Conversion_between_intrinsic_and_extrinsic_rotations and http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cg_Programming/Unity/Rotations (it's about Unity, but Unity uses the same left-hand system as Blender).

Answer (score 0):

I won't mark this as answer, as I don't understand *why* I'm seeing this behaviour when the whole point of extrinsic Euler rotations (as far as I can tell) is fixed world axis rotation, *but* Blender has exactly the same behaviour as my own app.

I'd like to think that someone in the last 20 years would have spotted a massive rotation flaw in Blender, so the behaviour I'm seeing must be expected...

If someone can explain why, I'll happily mark their answer as accepted!